# Can qplot directly display percentages without intermediate columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bunch of histograms to plot on data that is still coming. As the sample sizes vary, in order to compare them I need to plot the histograms with percentages not counts.

```
qplot (field, data=mydata, geom="histogram", binwidth=10)
```

the above qplot displays the counts. The *density* option is not applicable as it divides the counts within a bin to the bin's width, whereas I need to divide on the total number of samples.

I can precalculate a column containing the percentage, but it's cumbersome (I have many data sets).

Is there a better way to tell qplot to directly plot the histogram with percentages (ideally, also displayed as percentages (as 69%) and not as 0.69)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
ggplot(movies,aes(x=rating))+stat_bin(aes(n=nrow(movies), y=..count../n))+
scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent")
```

Comment: And the implicit advice of "don't use qplot unless you're a ggplot expert" is also excellent!

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run the example code:Error in continuous_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", "yintercept",  : 
  unused argument(s) (formatter = "percent")

Comment: I think the new way is scale_y_continuous(label = percent), but I can't find where this is documented.

Comment: @Ista: Documentation: [Changes and Additions to ggplot2-0.9.0](https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf), and `label` should be `labels`